# Divide one column into several variables in r

Tags: r, character

I have one column with multiple sets of variables as listed below. I have to divide this column into several variables. For example, this column has information about country, tax number, name, address, date, etc. I have to create multiple variables - Country : mx, Tax Number : DID100927249, etc.- from this column but I am not sure how to do it. Does anyone know how I can do this?

```
{'country': ['mx'], 'taxNumber': ['DID100927249'], 'sourceUrl': ['https://sanctionssearch.ofac.treas.gov/Details.aspx?id=13009'], 'name': ['DISPOSITIVOS INDUSTRIALES DINAMICOS, S.A. DE C.V.'], 'alias': ['DISDA'], 'topics': ['sanction'], 'addressEntity': ['addr-f1636ec5b03213730a35200572c1273749727da4'], 'createdAt': ['2012-04-12']}
```

I tried the following code but in each column the order of properties is different so it is not working well :(

```
separate(df, col=properties, into=c('a', 'b','c','d','e'), sep=',')
```

Comment: This looks like json -- look into the jsonlite package.

Comment: Can you use `dput` to show the structure i.e. `dput(head(df))`